# Dynamic checkBox length in java script

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jsp

I am getting some values from server in XML format using ajax. The format is like :

```
<employees><employee><id>Id</id><employeeName>Name</employeeName></employee>.....</employees>
```

So to process this response i use

```
 if(employees.childNodes.length>0){
                    for (loop = 0; loop <     employees.childNodes.length; loop++) {
                     var employee = employees.childNodes[loop];
                     var ids = employee.getElementsByTagName("id")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                     var name = employee.getElementsByTagName("employeeName")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
                     s=s+'<input name=\"userAction'+type+'\" id=\"userAction'+type+'\" value=\"'+ids+'\" type=\"checkbox"\/>'+name+'<br\/>';            


                   }
                                       document.getElementById('div'+type).innerHTML=s;                        
}
```

I am able to successfully show the no. of users in  . But my problem is when i click on submit function i want to know the length of no. of chekboxes. As u see i use the same name of all the checkoxes in a particular div.

```
var lennt=document.frm["userAction"+i].length;
                alert(lennt)
```

If there were more than 1 user the lenght is ok, but for one user it is giving me "undefined"
Please help me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have is if there are no elements named `"userAction"+i` then `document.frm["userAction"+i]` is `undefined`, if there is only 1 then `document.frm["userAction"+i]` is a reference to one DOM node so there is no `length` property, if there are > 1, `document.frm["userAction"+i]` is a reference to a DOMNodeList, so there IS a length property.  Solution: do some tests like so:

```
var checkboxes = document.frm["userAction"+i];
var lennt = 0; // default
if (checkboxes) { // checkboxes is not undefined
    // assign value based on whether checkboxes.length is defined
    lennt = (checkboxes.length) ? checkboxes.length : 1;
}
```